# postgres 11: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: postgresql, connections, max-connections

I've run into the following problem. From time to time, my app receives `remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections` from postgres. It lasts for quite noticeable periods of time, from several seconds to couple of minutes. I've checked pg_stat_activity at this very period, and it showed about five application backend connections, several pgAdmin connections, and some postgres-specific processes like replication, autovaccuum, wal-writing, etc -- about 20 processes in total, nothing peculiar. Then I checked `SHOW max_connections;` -- it was still 200.

I've no pooling, nothing except just postgres and a backend application.

How come?

Comment: Did you check superuser_reserved_connections to ensure it was not changed to some absurd value?

Comment: Do you find this same message in the db server's log file?  Perhaps the app has randomly decided to connect to some different database server, and that is the server delivering the error.

Comment: Silly me, it turned out I've been looking for a problem on a healthy slave, while the problem was on the other one... Many thanks @jjanes, your second comment helped me a lot.